# Fixed number of flex-items in one line when using flex-wrap

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following `HTML` and `CSS` code which you can also find in `JS fiddle` [here](https://jsfiddle.net/t9v8yfwp/3/).

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  float: left;

  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: Chartreuse;
}

.image {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 10%;

  background-color: green;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}

.image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}



.flex-container {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;

 width: 80%;
 margin-left: 10%;

 box-sizing: border-box;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 1px;
 background-color: red;
}


.flex-item{
 flex-basis: 25%;
 
 flex-grow: 1;
 flex-shrink: 1;

 padding-left: 5%;
 padding-right: 5%;

 box-sizing: border-box;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 1px;
 background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <main>
  
  <div class="image">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/101x101">
  </div>

  <div class="flex-container">
  
    <div class="flex-item">
    text of flex-item 1 goes into the box here.
    </div>
    
    <div class="flex-item">
    text of flex-item 2 goes into the box here.
    </div>
    
    <div class="flex-item">
    text of flex-item 3 goes into the box here.
    </div>
    
    <div class="flex-item">
    text of flex-item 4 goes into the box here.
    </div>
    
  </div>

  </main>

</body>
```

As you can see the code shows a webpage consisting of an `.image` and four `.flex-items` within a `.flex-container` below the `.image`. These flex-items are used to make the webpage responsive. Therefore, I applied the `.flex-wrap` property to it.

My issue is now that when I minimize the size from desktop to mobile the last `flex-item` will go entirely below the three other `flex items`. 
However, I want to achieve that **always at least 2 items are in one line** so in the case above when the last item goes one level lower the third item should go as well.

What do I need to change in my code to achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/a/55211366/8620333

Comment: @Temani Afif: I tried to apply your code from the answer in the duplicate here https://jsfiddle.net/xagj451n/ but now the items always remain in the same line without breaking at all. Do you see a mistake in my code?

Comment: add min-width to subcontainer (ex: min-width: 150px; )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With reference to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55211249/flex-items-to-two-rows-when-necessary/55211366#55211366) the solution is to divide the four items into two `sub-containers` where each container consists of two items and to add a `min-width: 150px;` to the main `.flex-container`. The code can be also found in the `JS fiddle` [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zk1nqyah/1/).

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  float: left;

  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: Chartreuse;
}

.image {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 10%;

  background-color: green;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}

.image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}



.flex-container {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;

 width: 80%;
 margin-left: 10%;

 box-sizing: border-box;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 1px;
 background-color: red;
}


.sub-container {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;

 flex-basis: 50%;
 flex-grow: 1;
 flex-shrink: 1;
 min-width: 150px; /* Neccessary to break the subcontainers in two lines */

 box-sizing: border-box;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 1px;
 background-color: red;
}


.flex-item {
 flex-basis: 50%;
 flex-grow: 1;
 flex-shrink: 1;

 padding-left: 5%;
 padding-right: 5%;

 box-sizing: border-box;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 1px;
 background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <main>
  
  <div class="image">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/101x101">
  </div>

 <div class="flex-container">
  
    <div class="sub-container">
    <div class="flex-item">text of flex-item 1 goes into the box here.
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">text of flex-item 2 goes into the box here.
    </div>
    </div>
  
    <div class="sub-container">
    <div class="flex-item">text of flex-item 3 goes into the box here.
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">text of flex-item 4 goes into the box here.
    </div>
    </div>
  
  </div>

  </main>

</body>
```

Comment: The items aren't stacking at all on mobile for me with this solution. Still four across.

Comment: This solution appears to work much better after moving the line `min-width: 150px; /* Neccessary to break the subcontainers in two lines */` from `.flex-container` to `.sub-container` and change `flex-wrap: wrap;` to `no-wrap` in `.sub-container`